# My implementation of lexicographic permutation in F# is 3x slower than C#

Tags: c#, f#, combinatorics, comparative-review

Can someone help me with the following micro optimization for the F# code for lexicographic permutation?

I have code in C# which runs for 0.8s. As a learning practice, I translated it into F#. However, it becomes 2.9s. Just out of curiosity, I am wondering why my code in F# runs that slow? Are there any improvement can be made to my F# code without changing the algorithm?

**C#**

```
 static bool ToNextLexicographic(int[] myArray)
    {
        int pivot = -1;

        for (int i = myArray.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (myArray[i] > myArray[i - 1])
            {
                pivot = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pivot == -1)
            return false;

        for (int j = myArray.Length - 1; j > pivot; j--)
        {
            if (myArray[j] > myArray[pivot])
            {
                // swap
                var tmp = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = myArray[pivot];
                myArray[pivot] = tmp;

                // reverse
                for (int i = pivot + 1, k = myArray.Length - 1; i < k;i++,k-- )
                {
                    var tmp = myArray[i];
                    myArray[i] = myArray[k];
                    myArray[k] = tmp;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    static IEnumerable<int[]> GetPermutationsLexicographic(int[] myArray)
    {
        Array.Sort(myArray);
        yield return myArray;

        while (ToNextLexicographic(myArray))
        {
            //yield return myArray.ToArray();
            yield return myArray;
        }
    }
```

**F#** (much readable than C#)

```
let inline toNextLexicographic (myArray: _[]) =
    let rec findPivot i =
        if i = 0 then -1
        else
            if myArray.[i] > myArray.[i-1] then i - 1
            else findPivot (i - 1)

    let rec findTarget value i =
        if (myArray.[i] > value) then i
        else findTarget value (i - 1)

    let inline swap i j =
        let tmp = myArray.[i]
        myArray.[i] <- myArray.[j]
        myArray.[j] <- tmp

    let inline reverse i =
        let mutable a = i
        let mutable b = myArray.Length - 1
        while a < b do
            swap a b
            a <- a + 1
            b <- b - 1

    let pivot = findPivot (myArray.Length - 1)
    if pivot = -1 then false
    else
        let target = findTarget myArray.[pivot] (myArray.Length - 1)
        swap pivot target
        reverse (pivot + 1)
        true;

let inline getPermutationsLexicographic myArray = seq {
    Array.sortInPlace myArray
    yield myArray
    while toNextLexicographic myArray do
        yield myArray
    }

// benchmark
let mutable d = 0
for x in getPermutationsLexicographic([|1..11|]) do
    d <- d + 1
d
```

Comment: Well, have you tried profiling the code to find out what slows it down?

Comment: @svick the profiling info shows difference between x64 and x86, even though I struggled to find anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now confirm the performance difference is due to `Seq / IEnumerable`

Say, if I remove `Seq / IEnumerable`, and meausre speed simply use `while` loop, e.g.

```
while toNextLexicographic myArray do
    d <- d + 2
```

The speed of C# and F# are now the same, being 0.6s. So I conclude it is the `IEnumerable` that make a difference. Still I don't get why `Seq` is slower than `IEnumerable` here, as they should be identical.

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing apples to apples. The F# code is generic whereas the C# only works with `int` arrays. Remove every occurrence of `inline` and add a type annotation to `toNextLexicographic`:

```
let toNextLexicographic (myArray: int[])
```

In my tests, that takes the time from 2.152 to 0.146 seconds.

The reason for the poor performance is `inline` isn't working. You can see this by decompiling. Most of the time is spent in `LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericGreaterThanIntrinsic` as a result. This is much more expensive than `op_GreaterThan`.

I'm not sure under what conditions `inline` is ignored, but I can only guess, in this case, it's due to the complexity of your code and the closures.

Comment: I did what you suggested, it still takes 2.2s, not improved at all. Also I updated the C# code in question so it becomes generic. (time spent stays the same)

Comment: Something's amiss. You added the type annotation and it stayed the same? I see a huge difference. After the change to the C#, you're still not comparing the same code. Change the F# to use `CompareTo`. `GenericGreaterThanIntrinsic` is slow. You want to eliminate those calls. Also, are you compiling in Release mode?

Comment: I updated the post so that you can see my changed F#, (it is nothing new but to add `int[]` and remove some `inline`) Since the C# version is 0.8s, I don't think you can get less than that in F#. Your result of 0.146s is suspicious. The reason why I use `inline` at the first place is that I know `GenericGreaterThanIntrinsic` (doesn't implement `IComparable<T>`) is slower than `CompareTo<T>`.

Comment: Can you update to include your test code?

Comment: Ok, done. Btw it doesn't seem that `inline` was broken. Without `inline` and without type annotation, the program takes 20s.

Comment: Have you decompiled this? It is not being `inline`d.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Not every function marked `inline` is actually inlined. Some remain generic.

Comment: Apologies, I am still not fully convinced. The update code with explicit type annotation takes 1.5s in x64 and 2.3s in x86.